# How can I exclude specific columns from a ColumnTransformer/Pipeline in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to build a data preprocessing pipeline with sklearn Pipeline and ColumnTransformer. The preprocessing steps consist of parallel imputting values and transforming (power transform, scaling or OHE) to specific columns. This preprocessing ColumnTransform works perfectly.

However, after doing some analysis on the preprocessed result, I decided to exclude some columns from the final result. My goal is to have one pipeline starting from the original dataframe that inputs and transforms values, excludes pre-selected columns, and triggers the model fitting all in one. So to be clear, I don't want to drop columns after the pipeline is fitted/transformed. I want instead that the process of dropping columns is part of the column transformation.

It's easy to remove the numerical columns from the model (by simply not adding them), but how can I exclude the columns created by OHE? I don't want to exclude all columns created by OHE, just some of them. For example, if categorical column "Example" becomes Example_1, Example_2, and Example_3, how can I exclude only Example_2?

Example code:

```
### Importing libraries
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
SimpleImputer.get_feature_names_out = (lambda self, names = None: self.feature_names_in_) # SimpleImputer does not have get_feature_names_out, so we need to add it manually.
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer


### Dummy dataframe
df_foo = pd.DataFrame({'Num_col' : [1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,9],
                       'Example' : ['A','B','C','A','B','A','A','C','C'], 
                       'another_col' : range(10,100,10)})

### Pipelines
SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler = Pipeline([
    ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")),
    ('MinMaxScaler', MinMaxScaler()),
])
SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE = Pipeline([
    ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value='no_answer')),
    ('OHE', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop='if_binary', categories='auto')),
])

### ColumnTransformer
preprocessor_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('pipeline-1', SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler, ['Num_col']),
    ('pipeline-2', SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE, ['Example'])
     ],
    remainder='drop',
    verbose_feature_names_out=False)
preprocessor_transformer


### Preprocessing dummy dataframe
df_foo = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor_transformer.fit_transform(df_foo), 
            columns=preprocessor_transformer.get_feature_names_out()
            )
print(df_foo)
```

Finally, I've seen this solution out there ([Adding Dropping Column instance into a Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402691/adding-dropping-column-instance-into-a-pipeline)) but I didn't manage to make the custom columnDropperTransformer to work in my case. Adding the columnDropperTransformer to my pipeline returns an ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe, refering to column "Example" not existing in the dataframe anymore.

```
class columnDropperTransformer():
    def __init__(self,columns):
        self.columns=columns

    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        return X.drop(self.columns,axis=1)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 

processor= make_pipeline(preprocessor_transformer,columnDropperTransformer([]))

processor.fit_transform(df_foo)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience and as of today, automating these kinds of treatments in `sklearn` is not that easy for the following reasons:

- the steps performed by the `Pipeline` (when calling `.fit_transform()` on it) make you lose the DataFrame structure (the *pandas DataFrame* becomes a *numpy array*). I'd suggest reading

  [How to be sure that sklearn piepline applies fit_transform method when using feature selection and ML model in piepline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103556/how-to-be-sure-that-sklearn-piepline-applies-fit-transform-method-when-using-fea/73106771#73106771)
  and [how to use ColumnTransformer() to return a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933014/how-to-use-columntransformer-to-return-a-dataframe/70934371#70934371)

  for some details on what happens when calling `.fit()` or
  `.fit_transform()` on a `Pipeline` instance.
- In turn, "columns" in a *numpy array* can't be referenced anymore via their names, but only positionally.

Here are a couple of solutions which are ***not scalable*** imo, but that can work for your case:

1. You can add a step in your pipeline which is only intended to transform the *numpy array* (which is the standard output of the intermediate transformations performed by the pipeline) back in a *pandas DataFrame* (via the `ColumnExtractor` transformer). Once you have a DataFrame, you can exploit the `columnDropperTransformer` of the referenced link to drop the column `Example_B` via its name.

   ```
   from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

   class ColumnExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
       def __init__(self, columns):
           self.columns = columns

       def transform(self, X, *_):
           return pd.DataFrame(X, columns=self.columns)

       def fit(self, *_):
           return self

   class columnDropperTransformer():
       def __init__(self,columns):
           self.columns=columns

       def transform(self,X,y=None):
           return X.drop(self.columns,axis=1)

       def fit(self, X, y=None):
           return self
   ```

   The `ColumnExtractor` transformer is only intended to map the resulting array in a DataFrame. The clear disadvantage is that you'll need to manually specify the columns you would like your DataFrame to be made of.

   ```
   from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
   SimpleImputer.get_feature_names_out = (lambda self, names = None: self.feature_names_in_) # SimpleImputer does not have get_feature_names_out, so we need to add it manually.
   from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
   from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
   from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
   from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   ### Dummy dataframe
   df_foo = pd.DataFrame({'Num_col' : [1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,9],
                  'Example' : ['A','B','C','A','B','A','A','C','C'], 
                  'another_col' : range(10,100,10)})

   SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler = Pipeline([
       ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")),
       ('MinMaxScaler', MinMaxScaler()),
   ])
   SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE = Pipeline([
       ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value='no_answer')),
       ('OHE', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop='if_binary', categories='auto')),
   ])

   ### ColumnTransformer
   preprocessor_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
       ('pipeline-1', SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler, ['Num_col']),
       ('pipeline-2', SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE, ['Example'])
   ],
   remainder='drop',
   verbose_feature_names_out=False)

   processor = make_pipeline(
       preprocessor_transformer, 
       ColumnExtractor(['Num_col', 'Example_A', 'Example_B', 'Example_C']))

   f_processor = make_pipeline(
       processor, 
       columnDropperTransformer('Example_B'))

   f_processor.fit_transform(df_foo)
   ```
2. You can reference the "columns" of the array which comes out from the application of the `Pipeline` transformations *positionally* (i.e. by index). For instance, you might define such a dummy transformer

   ```
   class NumpyColumnSelector():
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def transform(self,X,y=None):
           return X[:, [0, 1, 3]]

       def fit(self, X, y=None):
           return self
   ```

   which only retains all columns but the one which would correspond to the `Example_B` one.

   ```
   from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
   SimpleImputer.get_feature_names_out = (lambda self, names = None: self.feature_names_in_) # SimpleImputer does not have get_feature_names_out, so we need to add it manually.
   from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
   from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
   from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
   from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
   from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   ### Dummy dataframe
   df_foo = pd.DataFrame({'Num_col' : [1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,9],
                  'Example' : ['A','B','C','A','B','A','A','C','C'], 
                  'another_col' : range(10,100,10)})  

   SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler = Pipeline([
       ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")),
       ('MinMaxScaler', MinMaxScaler()),
   ])
   SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE = Pipeline([
       ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value='no_answer')),
       ('OHE', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop='if_binary', categories='auto')),
   ])

   ### ColumnTransformer
   preprocessor_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
       ('pipeline-1', SimpImpMean_MinMaxScaler, ['Num_col']),
       ('pipeline-2', SimpImpConstNoAns_OHE, ['Example'])
   ],
   remainder='drop',
   verbose_feature_names_out=False)

   f_processor = make_pipeline(preprocessor_transformer, NumpyColumnSelector())

   f_processor.fit_transform(df_foo)
   ```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to giving such a detailed explanation. Pretty smart solutions but indeed your solutions are not scalable and won't be useful to my case :(

I must add that after reading into the topic further I decided to NOT exclude OHE-features at all anymore. There are some sound reasons for that in general, but in my case it actually improves the model (tiny improvement) and solves my problem.
For more details: https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/drop-first-columns/

Answer (score 1):

For the very specific use-case of removing dummy columns generated by the OHE (+1 to amiola for a more generic answer), you can specify `categories` and `handle_unknown='ignore'`.  In your example, replacing the OHE line by this:

```
('OHE', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories=[['A', 'C']], handle_unknown='ignore')),
```

produces this:

```py
    Num_col  Example_A  Example_C
0  0.000000        1.0        0.0
1  0.125000        0.0        0.0
2  0.482143        0.0        1.0
3  0.375000        1.0        0.0
4  0.500000        0.0        0.0
5  0.625000        1.0        0.0
6  0.750000        1.0        0.0
7  0.482143        0.0        1.0
8  1.000000        0.0        1.0
```